# Can anyone help to explain one of the variables in a figure that illustrates how posterior probabilities shift and move around?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, neural-networks, naive-bayes

I am learning [this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter1_Introduction/Ch1_Introduction_PyMC2.ipynb) post.

The book gives this figure to illustrate how posterior probabilities shift and move around

[image]

Here is the code

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
figsize(11, 9)

import scipy.stats as stats

dist = stats.beta
n_trials = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 15, 50, 500]
data = stats.bernoulli.rvs(0.5, size=n_trials[-1])
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

# For the already prepared, I'm using Binomial's conj. prior.
for k, N in enumerate(n_trials):
    sx = plt.subplot(len(n_trials) / 2, 2, k + 1)
    plt.xlabel("$p$, probability of heads") \
        if k in [0, len(n_trials) - 1] else None
    plt.setp(sx.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    heads = data[:N].sum()
    y = dist.pdf(x, 1 + heads, 1 + N - heads)
    plt.plot(x, y, label="observe %d tosses,\n %d heads" % (N, heads))
    plt.fill_between(x, 0, y, color="#348ABD", alpha=0.4)
    plt.vlines(0.5, 0, 4, color="k", linestyles="--", lw=1)

    leg = plt.legend()
    leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)
    plt.autoscale(tight=True)


plt.suptitle("Bayesian updating of posterior probabilities",
             y=1.02,
             fontsize=14)

plt.tight_layout()
```

Each element in the `n_trials` list indicates how many times a coin has been tossed.

`data` represents the records of the trials of tossing a coin.

what does this line mean?

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
```

Comment: I believe it creates a linear set of values starting with the first argument, 0, finishing with the second argument, 1, and creating 100-2 = 98 linearly spaced values in between.  In this case x would be [ 0  0.0101  0.0202  0.0303  ...  0.9899 1 ].  It is used in this example as the x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for simplicity, start with this figure to illustrate the mechanism, others also hold.

[image]

in this case, x ranges from 0 to 1, y from 2 to 0.

y represents a pdf, which indicates a function has a 2% probability to get a 0 for the value of x, 1.98% probability for 0.01.

naive Bayes model learned from data, adjust its guess from equally likely to 0 has the highest probability (2%).

more data comes in, naive Bayes model has a more precise guess about the pdf, eventually the model guess the 0.5 has the highest probability, this is the last figure.